# Vue.js unexpected data and method behaviour

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue.js component with simple template

```
<div @click="createTargets(2)">
text
</div>
```

and script file is

```
export default {
  name: 'test',
  data() {
    return {
      targets: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    createTargets(targetCount) {
      this.targets = [];
      var emptyTarget = {
          id: null,
      };
      for (var i = 0; i < targetCount; i++) {
        var targetToPush = emptyTarget;
        targetToPush.id = i;
        console.log(targetToPush.id);
        this.targets.push(targetToPush);
        console.log(this.targets);
      }
      return {};
    },
  },
}
```

When I click `text`, I get output

```
0
[{"id":1},{"id":1}]
1
[{"id":1},{"id":1}]
```

I cannot figure out why this is happening.

I would expect

```
0
[{"id":0}]
1
[{"id":0},{"id":1}]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have a single `emptyTarget` object that you keep updating and pushing. A reference to an object is not a *copy* of an object.

Comment: Oh, so instead of `var targetToPush = emptyTarget` I should use `= {...emptyTarget}`. Thank you. But still, the second console log gives me `[{"id":0},{"id":1}]` just like the fourth one, when I would expect just `[{"id":0}]`. Why?

Comment: You could check if it's a race condition of the browser with; `setTimeout(() => {console.log(this.targets);}, 10);

Comment: `console.log`s will update themselves over time; it's not always useful for tracking processes over time if it's logging object refs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is quite simple really, an object is initialized only once, when it is assigned to a variable. If you assign this variable to a new variable, you are assigning the same object reference to a new variable. Updating Object1 will update Object2 and vice versa.

To circumvent this behavior, you can create a copy of the object when initializing Object2 using the new spread operator:

```js
const targets = [];
const common = { commonProp: 'test' };

for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
  const target = { ...common, id: i };
  targets.push(target);
}

this.targets = targets;
```

Note that you should avoid mutating your component's state in a loop. Even though the render loop is optimized and won't actually render `count` times, it's still better to mutate your property only once as per example.

Also note that nested objects behave the same way. The solution above is called a shallow copy, in contrast, a deep copy will recursively crawl your object to copy sub objects/arrays.

```js
const common = {
  commonProp: { a: 1, b: 2 }
};
const object1 = { ...common, id: 1 };
const object2 = { ...common, id: 2 };
object1.commonProp.a = 2;
console.log(object1); // { commonProp: { a: 2, b: 2 } }
console.log(object2); // { commonProp: { a: 2, b: 2 } }
```

To avoid this issue, you can use a library to deep copy an object/array or create a class or factory function that will return a new object every time it is called.

```js
// factory
const createTarget = id => ({
  commonProp: { a: 1, b: 2 },
  id,
});

// class
class Target {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.commonProp = { a: 1, b: 2 };
  }
}

for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
  const target = createTarget(i); // or new Target(i);
  targets.push(target);
}
```

I hope this explanation helped you understand this concept a bit better.

Good luck ;)

Answer (score 2):

[console.log()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)

> Please be warned that if you log objects in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox what you get logged on the console is a reference to the object, which is not necessarily the 'value' of the object at the moment in time you call `console.log()`, but it is the value of the object at the moment you open the console

> Don't use `console.log(obj)`, use `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)))`

Answer (score 0):

You might print the array values (not the reference):

```
for (var i = 0; i < targetCount; i++) {
  var targetToPush = emptyTarget;
  targetToPush.id = i;
  console.log(targetToPush.id);
  this.targets.push(targetToPush);

  // like this (es6 way):
  console.log([...this.targets]);

  // or like this (old way):
  console.log(this.targets.slice());
}
```

When you `console.log(this.targets)` you are printing directly the variable reference, and it's values will be chaging in the next loop, so it's also going to be changed in the browser console.

When you `console.log([...this.targets])` you are printing the array values (not the reference) of that given loop interaction and they will stay the same, even if the array changes later.

Answer (score 0):

the main problem , you are updating the reference variable, so it i will keep always the latest data.
just do like below hope problem will solve

```
createTargets(targetCount) {
      this.targets = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < targetCount; i++) {
        var targetToPush = {id: null};
        targetToPush.id = i;
        console.log(targetToPush.id);
        this.targets.push(targetToPush);
        console.log(this.targets);
      }
      return {};
    }
```