# undefined the properity of object in vue js but the propertiy exist in object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

is there anyone who can help me with this, I define a module that has a function, this function returns an object. when I call this function the object is received but when I want to access the element of the object which is status, said undefined.

this is my module:

```
import firebaseapp from "./firebase";
import store from "../store/index";
const database = firebaseapp.firebase.database();

export default {
  createProject(info) {
    var result = {};
    var userId = store.state.user.user.uid;
    info.created_at = firebaseapp.firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
    info.status = "pendning";
    info.ower = userId;
    const project_ref = database.ref("/projects/" + userId + "/");
    project_ref
      .push()
      .set(info)
      .then(function() {
        result.status = "1";
        result.message = "successfully created";
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        result.status = "0";
        result.message = error.message;
      });
    return result;
  }
};
```

here is I want to call the modules

```
export default {
data() {
    return {
      result: {},
      project: {
        ideal_expert: {}
      }
    };
  },
 gotCreateProject() {
      if (this.$refs.project_form.validate()) {
        this.dialog = true;
        this.result = create_project.createProject(this.project);
        console.log(this.result); //the whole object
        console.log(this.result.status);// the status property of object
      } else {
        this.dialog = false;
      }
      // console.log(this.dialog);
    }
  }
};
```

the output:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66642483/381282

Comment: I check this but not helpful

Comment: Not helpful in what way? Did you try the code suggested?

Comment: yes, i tried but give some error

Answer (score 1):

There are few problem with your code

1. Seemingly inconsistent logs - Modern browsers log objects as live references. What you see in the console is not the value of object at the time `console.log` was executed. [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66642483/381282) (yes, again)

Also take a look at the little example below. Open browser's Dev Tools and execute the snippet. Check browser's console - both logs should show empty object but 1st is showing object with property `a` which is assigned after the logging operation...

2. Because at the time you are logging the object and it's property, the object is empty **for sure**. Because inside `createProject` function you are calling asynchronous function `set(info)` which returns [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Everything inside `then` will be executed sometime in the future **but definitely** after `return result` and `console.log`
3. Judging by the log (`__ob__`) you are using Vue 2. Adding properties to a objects is an operation Vue cannot detect - see [Change Detection Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects). Define all properties beforeheand or use `Vue.set` as described in the docs

```js
let obj = {}

console.log("Log 1:", obj)
console.log("Log 2:", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)))

obj.a = 1
```